# Check if the object is of type Dictionary or Union of Dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, typeof, generic-collections

I have a function

```
public static async void MyFunction(object Obj)
{
    if (Obj.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, string>))
    {
        // My Code
    }
}
```

I want to check if parameter `Obj`  is of type `Dictionary<string, string>` or `Dictionary<string, string>.Union(Dictionary<string, string>)`.

What `||` condition should I put in the above `if` statement so that it will execute `if` block if the object passed to the function is of type *Dictioary* or *Union of Dictionaries*?

How do I do it?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but the output of `Dictionary<string, string>.Union(Dictionary<string, string>)` will be `Dictionary<string, string>`, won't it? ie there is no structure `Dictionary<string, string>.Union(Dictionary<string, string>)`. It sounds like maybe you will need to look at the data to se if the union has occurred or not.

Comment: @Jonathan: no, the type returned from the LINQ `Union` will be `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. @OP: Note that `Union`  on two dictionaries is not comparing the keys alone, so it's not safe if you want unique keys.

Comment: If I do `GetType()` on dictionary union, I get as follows : System.Linq.Enumerable+<UnionIterator>d__67`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]]

Comment: why not simply make the function signature MyFunction(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> values) ?

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension method:

```
public static bool IsAssignableToGenericType(this Type givenType, Type genericType) {
    if (givenType.IsGenericType && givenType.IsGenericEqual(genericType))
        return true;

    if (givenType.GetInterface(genericType.Name) != null)
        return true;

    foreach (var it in givenType.GetInterfaces())
        if (it.IsAssignableToGenericType(genericType))
            return true;

    var baseType = givenType.BaseType;
    if (baseType == null)
        return false;

    return baseType.IsAssignableToGenericType(genericType);
}
```

You can test:

```
if (Obj.GetType().IsAssignableToGenericType(typeof(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>))) {
```

This does not guarantee `Obj` is the product of a call to `Union`. If you need to do that, you need to delve into the type.

Using some extension methods to make Reflection easier:

```
public static class ObjectExt {
    public static object GetPrivateValue<T>(this T obj, string memberName) =>
        obj.GetType().GetPropertyOrField(memberName, BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(obj);
}

public static class TypeExt {
    public static MemberInfo GetPropertyOrField(this Type t, string memberName, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
        t.GetMember(memberName, bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).Single();
}

public static class MemberInfoExt {
    public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case MethodInfo mi:
                return mi.Invoke(srcObject, null);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or MethodInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
}
```

You can determine that the object is from a `Union` of `Dictionary`. Note that this depends on internals of .Net Core and may not work in the future:

```
var isDictUnion = (Obj.GetType() == unionType) && (Obj.GetPrivateValue("_first").GetType() == dictType) && (Obj.GetPrivateValue("_second").GetType() == dictType);
```